# Expected value of die rolls

Tags: probability

You have two six-sided dice. Die A has 2 twos, 1 three, 1 five, 1 ten, and 1 fourteen on its faces. Die B has a one, a three, a five, a seven, a nine, and an eleven on its faces.

I calculated that both have an expected value of six. If this is correct, then how do I interpret this? None of the dice have values of six, so what does it mean for me to expect their both of their values to be six?

In addition, I am posed with the question "On any given roll of both dice, what is the probability that the number showing on die A will be greater than the number on die B? What is the probability that the number showing on die B will be greater?"

I calculated P(A > B) = 4/9 and P(B > A) = 1/2. If these are the correct answers, then why aren't they the same of the expected values are the same? How is the A die greater than the B Die on average if they have the same expected values?

Comment: Throw a standard fair die.  The expected value (average of the faces) is $3.5$ but no face has $3.5$ on it.

Comment: Also read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice

Answer (score 0):

Let's play a game. There will 20 rounds on this game, on each round you can choose between two options:

1. You roll dice A and I give you that amount of dollars (dice A has faces 2,2,3,5,10,14, you have a 1/6 chance of getting 14, also 1/6 chance of getting 3)
2. You don't roll the dice and I give you $x$ dollars.

What is your best strategy?

Turns out it depends on the value of $x$. If $x$ is smaller than the expected value of the dice, choose the dice. If $x$ is greater than the expected value of the dice, choose $x$.

This is how I interpret the expected value of the dice. On the long run, it's the equivalent amount of money you would have gained, if you threw the dice many times (throw the dice 20 times, then the money will be pretty close to $20x$). This value doesn't have to be equal to any given side of the dice.